# Simple Wordpress Plugin PayPal

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins, paypal

how can I create a simple plugin for wordpress with a button, when you have made ​​the purchase, only one function to write to mysql id_user, purchase date and txn_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) for that.  It will POST transaction data to a listener script you have on your server in real-time so you can automatically update your database, send out email notifications, etc.

You'll get IPN's for all sorts of transactions like payments, refunds, disputes, pending payments that have cleared or failed, subscription profiles, subscription payments, etc.  You can use IPN to handle all of them however you need to.

As for the [WordPress plugin development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) you really just need to get familiar with plugin development in general and then creating an IPN listener for WordPress won't be a big deal for you.